# How to send a Google Places Search Request with Java

Tags: java, google-places-api

I need to search Goolge Places Pages by long/lat for any banks in the area of 20m.
This [Google Places Doc](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_search_requests) describes how to do it with JavaScript. They are using a `google.maps.LatLng` Object that i don't have in Java.

Does anyone now how to call the Service?

Maybe there is also an Java API for Goolge Places?

Best Regards,
Christian.

Edit 1:

I found [someone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865738/how-to-show-near-places-using-google-places-api) constructing the url like this:

```
String url = baseUrl + "location=" + lat + "," + lon + "&" +
                 "radius=" + searchRadius + "&" + types + "&" + "sensor=true" +
                 "&" + "key=" + googleAPIKey;
```

Answer: Edit 2:

I because of the post above i found out how to do it. This is a example how to send the request:

```
public class GooglePlacesClient
{
    private static final String GOOGLE_API_KEY  = "***";

    private final HttpClient    client          = new DefaultHttpClient();

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws ParseException, IOException, URISyntaxException
    {
        new GooglePlacesClient().performSearch("establishment", 8.6668310, 50.1093060);
    }

    public void performSearch(final String types, final double lon, final double lat) throws ParseException, IOException, URISyntaxException
    {
        final URIBuilder builder = new URIBuilder().setScheme("https").setHost("maps.googleapis.com").setPath("/maps/api/place/search/json");

        builder.addParameter("location", lat + "," + lon);
        builder.addParameter("radius", "5");
        builder.addParameter("types", types);
        builder.addParameter("sensor", "true");
        builder.addParameter("key", GooglePlacesClient.GOOGLE_API_KEY);

        final HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet(builder.build());

        final HttpResponse execute = this.client.execute(request);

        final String response = EntityUtils.toString(execute.getEntity());

        System.out.println(response);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here's a more complete example (includes JSON parsing and some exception handling) for Places API search, autocomplete, and details. It was written for Android, but can be easily ported for non-Android use (need to include org.json libs and use different logging). The `Place` class is a simple value object.

```
package com.example.google.places;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * @author saxman
 */
public class PlacesService {
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "ExampleApp";

    private static final String PLACES_API_BASE = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place";

    private static final String TYPE_AUTOCOMPLETE = "/autocomplete";
    private static final String TYPE_DETAILS = "/details";
    private static final String TYPE_SEARCH = "/search";

    private static final String OUT_JSON = "/json";

    // KEY!
    private static final String API_KEY = "YOUR KEY";

    public static ArrayList<Place> autocomplete(String input) {
        ArrayList<Place> resultList = null;

        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        StringBuilder jsonResults = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(PLACES_API_BASE);
            sb.append(TYPE_AUTOCOMPLETE);
            sb.append(OUT_JSON);
            sb.append("?sensor=false");
            sb.append("&key=" + API_KEY);
            sb.append("&input=" + URLEncoder.encode(input, "utf8"));

            URL url = new URL(sb.toString());
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());

            int read;
            char[] buff = new char[1024];
            while ((read = in.read(buff)) != -1) {
                jsonResults.append(buff, 0, read);
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error processing Places API URL", e);
            return resultList;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error connecting to Places API", e);
            return resultList;
        } finally {
            if (conn != null) {
                conn.disconnect();
            }
        }

        try {
            // Create a JSON object hierarchy from the results
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonResults.toString());
            JSONArray predsJsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("predictions");

            // Extract the Place descriptions from the results
            resultList = new ArrayList<Place>(predsJsonArray.length());
            for (int i = 0; i < predsJsonArray.length(); i++) {
                Place place = new Place();
                place.reference = predsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("reference");
                place.name = predsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("description");
                resultList.add(place);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error processing JSON results", e);
        }

        return resultList;
    }

    public static ArrayList<Place> search(String keyword, double lat, double lng, int radius) {
        ArrayList<Place> resultList = null;

        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        StringBuilder jsonResults = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(PLACES_API_BASE);
            sb.append(TYPE_SEARCH);
            sb.append(OUT_JSON);
            sb.append("?sensor=false");
            sb.append("&key=" + API_KEY);
            sb.append("&keyword=" + URLEncoder.encode(keyword, "utf8"));
            sb.append("&location=" + String.valueOf(lat) + "," + String.valueOf(lng));
            sb.append("&radius=" + String.valueOf(radius));

            URL url = new URL(sb.toString());
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());

            int read;
            char[] buff = new char[1024];
            while ((read = in.read(buff)) != -1) {
                jsonResults.append(buff, 0, read);
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error processing Places API URL", e);
            return resultList;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error connecting to Places API", e);
            return resultList;
        } finally {
            if (conn != null) {
                conn.disconnect();
            }
        }

        try {
            // Create a JSON object hierarchy from the results
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonResults.toString());
            JSONArray predsJsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("results");

            // Extract the Place descriptions from the results
            resultList = new ArrayList<Place>(predsJsonArray.length());
            for (int i = 0; i < predsJsonArray.length(); i++) {
                Place place = new Place();
                place.reference = predsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("reference");
                place.name = predsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("name");
                resultList.add(place);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error processing JSON results", e);
        }

        return resultList;
    }

    public static Place details(String reference) {
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        StringBuilder jsonResults = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(PLACES_API_BASE);
            sb.append(TYPE_DETAILS);
            sb.append(OUT_JSON);
            sb.append("?sensor=false");
            sb.append("&key=" + API_KEY);
            sb.append("&reference=" + URLEncoder.encode(reference, "utf8"));

            URL url = new URL(sb.toString());
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());

            // Load the results into a StringBuilder
            int read;
            char[] buff = new char[1024];
            while ((read = in.read(buff)) != -1) {
                jsonResults.append(buff, 0, read);
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error processing Places API URL", e);
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error connecting to Places API", e);
            return null;
        } finally {
            if (conn != null) {
                conn.disconnect();
            }
        }

        Place place = null;
        try {
            // Create a JSON object hierarchy from the results
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonResults.toString()).getJSONObject("result");

            place = new Place();
            place.icon = jsonObj.getString("icon");
            place.name = jsonObj.getString("name");
            place.formatted_address = jsonObj.getString("formatted_address");
            if (jsonObj.has("formatted_phone_number")) {
                place.formatted_phone_number = jsonObj.getString("formatted_phone_number");
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error processing JSON results", e);
        }

        return place;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you you save my life 
:)

Answer (score 12):

A Java library for working with the Google Places API is available on GitHub and in Maven Central (disclosure: I'm the developer.)  Getting a list of places (or details, photo, etc.) can be done in one or two lines.  See the project page for examples and set up details.

https://github.com/pushbit/sprockets

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't exist any official Java library available for Google Places API. However, there are several projects hosted on Github. Another one is this:
[Google Places API Java Library on Github](https://github.com/skd1993/google-places-api-java)

Comment: It should be noted that the linked repository is a fork of the original project. The original repo is located [here](https://github.com/windy1/google-places-api-java)

Comment: Be careful. Comment above contains another forked SDK. It might contain vulnerabilities. Here're official docs with links to official GitHub repos: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/client-library

Answer (score 0):

You can use official [Java Client](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/client-library) for Google Maps (includes Places API)

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.maps</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-maps-services</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.25</version>
    </dependency>
```

for nearbySearch

```
public static List<PlacesSearchResult> nearbySearch(double lat, double lng, int radiusInMeters) {
    List<PlacesSearchResult> results = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        GeoApiContext ctx = new GeoApiContext.Builder().apiKey(API_KEY).build();
        PlacesSearchResponse response = PlacesApi.nearbySearchQuery(ctx, new LatLng(lat, lng))
            .type(PlaceType.RESTAURANT)
            .radius(radiusInMeters)
            .await();

        results.addAll(Arrays.asList(response.results));

        int page = 1; // Google Maps API provides maximum 60 results by search (3 pages maximum, each containing 20 records)
        while (response.nextPageToken != null && !response.nextPageToken.isBlank() && response.results.length == 20 && page <= 2) {
            Thread.sleep(3000); // Google has SLA for no more than N requests per second in free tier
            response = PlacesApi.nearbySearchNextPage(ctx, response.nextPageToken).await();
            results.addAll(Arrays.asList(response.results));
            page++;
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        }

    } catch (ApiException e) {
        logger.error("ApiException: ", e);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        logger.error("InterruptedException: ", e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error("IOException: ", e);
    }

    return results;
}
```

for findPlace

```
public static PlacesSearchResult[] findPlace(double lat, double lng) {
    GeoApiContext ctx = new GeoApiContext.Builder().apiKey(API_KEY).build();

    FindPlaceFromText response = null;
    try {
        response = PlacesApi.findPlaceFromText(ctx, "restaurants", FindPlaceFromTextRequest.InputType.TEXT_QUERY)
            .fields(
                FindPlaceFromTextRequest.FieldMask.NAME,
                FindPlaceFromTextRequest.FieldMask.FORMATTED_ADDRESS,
                FindPlaceFromTextRequest.FieldMask.RATING,
                FindPlaceFromTextRequest.FieldMask.OPENING_HOURS)
            .locationBias(new FindPlaceFromTextRequest.LocationBiasCircular(new LatLng(lat, lng), 10000))
            .await();
    } catch (ApiException e) {
        logger.error("ApiException: ", e);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        logger.error("InterruptedException: ", e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error("IOException: ", e);
    }
    
    return response != null ? response.candidates : null;
}
```