# How to get location's address when i have latitude and longitude in java?

Tags: java

i am getting certain latitude and longitude from the GPS device. I have to know the address of the place. How that i can do in java. Is there any API that google provides in java to know the address when i know the latitude and longitude?

Comment: The Google Maps API v3 is javascript so, if your question is about Java, it is not about the Google Maps API.

Answer (score 3):

In the following Example, there are included two main concepts.

1. [Web Service client(Reverse geocoding)](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start)
2. JSON

Web Services client is used to access resource from another server which is provide some web service

Using this service, you can get address use of Latitude, Longitude

Google are Providing Free web service client URI
That is

```
"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=<LATITUDE>,<LONGITUDE> &key=<ENTER YOUR PLACE API KEY HEAR>
```

Use that service You can get all type of address in JSON format from Google place API

After You can Find Your required objects and value from JSON data

I give You formatted_address from that JSON data

There are Following Code to Get Location Address Using Latitude,longitude

```
package clientpkg;

import java.net.URI;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;  
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;  
import javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;  
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;  
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder;  
import org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig;

import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;

public class MapAdd
{
    public static void main(String...aa)
    {
        try
        {
            System.out.println("Finding Address...\n");
            ClientConfig config = new ClientConfig();
            Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(config);
            WebTarget target = client.target(getBaseURI());

            String jsonaddresss =  target.request().accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(String.class);

            String address = adres(jsonaddresss);


            System.out.println("Perfect Address is : >>"+address);

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error"+e);
        }
    }

    private static URI getBaseURI()
    {
        return UriBuilder.fromUri("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=32.263200,50.778187&key=<ENTER YOUR PLACE API KEY HEAR >").build();
    }
    private static String adres(String jsonaddresss)
    {
        try
        {
            JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

            Object obj = parser.parse(jsonaddresss);
            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;

            JSONArray msg = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("results");

            //System.out.println("Message"+msg.get(1)); //Get Second Line Of Result

            JSONObject jobj = (JSONObject) parser.parse(msg.get(1).toString()); // Parsse it 

            String perfect_address = jobj.get("formatted_address").toString();

            jsonaddresss = perfect_address;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            jsonaddresss = "Error In Address"+e;
        }
        return jsonaddresss;
    }
}
```

Comment: please add an explanation to what you're doing, instead of just adding a code block

Comment: Exactly what I wanted :D

Answer (score 2):

Google's [Geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding) and [Places API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/) does exactly what you want.

Comment: Yes, but all are done in javascript. I am new to google api. Can you help me how can i get the exact thing.

Comment: So you are really asking how to query a RESTful Service. Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12460471/how-to-send-a-google-places-search-request-with-java

Comment: You can use the geocoding service through an http request from any language: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding